# why the last number of the exercise is NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

im doing a exercise of bills, tips and total of the all.

```js
const calcTip = function (bill) {
  return bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? bill * 0.15 : bill * 0.2;
};

const billsArray = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52];
const tipsArray = [];
const totalsArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= billsArray.length; i++) {
  const tip = calcTip(billsArray[i]);
  tipsArray.push(tip);
  totalsArray.push(tip + billsArray[i]);
}

console.log(billsArray, tipsArray, totalsArray);
```

It's all right but in the browser console said that last one is not a number? someone knows why? do i need to use float?
[image]

Comment: You need to use `<` not `<=` in your loop

Comment: @Lee Taylor nice, I didn’t notice that

Comment: Mine actually returns `null`

Answer (score 3):

it's because you didn't set condition `<=` exactly in for loop. it should be `i<billsArray.length`

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you.

Comment: This works. I’ve tested both myself and it works now,

Answer (score 1):

It's because of out of array index `i <= billsArray.length`

can fixable with `i < billsArray.length` or `i <= billsArray.length - 1`